# Resizing image to fit changing browser window

Tags: html, css

How to resize an image to adjust with browser window? I would like the image to fit within the white box. I have the following code:

```
.image { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What should the image size be to fit both large and small browser windows? Current photo is ~900px wide.
[image: banner]

**Update**

This is code from the template I am using from Dreamweaver:

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If the max-width is 1260px, should the image be 1260px? And then have it scale down the image as the browser window shrinks?

Comment: Try adding `display:block`, and make sure all the parent nodes are also `width: 100%`

Comment: The code you have written should make the image expand fully over the white space if that is the parent element. You probably have other css that prevents that from happening

Comment: I tried the display:block, but it didn't change anything. I think you are right, it must be something from the parent element. I have the image width set to 100%, shouldn't it fit the container regardless?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pure CSS and does not even require media queries.
*To make the images flexible, simply add max-width:100% and height:auto. Image max-width:100% and height:auto works in IE7, but not in IE8 (yes, another weird IE bug). To fix this, you need to add width:auto\9 for IE8.*
CSS:

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

f you want to enforce a fixed max width of the image, just place it inside a container:

```
<div style="max-width:500px;">
<img src="..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply css code:

```
img {width: 100% }
```

this should do the trick...

Comment: I did try that, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. I must be doing something else wrong, but I can't figure it out because I hardly have any code.